# How to scroll menu from left to right and vice versa in android

Tags: android, view, android-linearlayout, android-framelayout

Hi Can u please tell how to move menu bars from left to right or right to left

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by menu bars?

Answer (score 1):

For your concern use HorizontalScrollView.. Check this out ..

```
<HorizontalScrollView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10sp"
                    android:scrollbars="horizontal" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >
                    </LinearLayout>
                </HorizontalScrollView>
```